# For what b does Ax = b have infinitely many solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-2&-1\end{bmatrix}

I reduced it to

\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}

But I don't understand where to go from here
the hint says that it is a linear combination of the columns of Ax
of columns of A

Comment: If $Ax = 0$, then $Akx = 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you know for which $b$ it has a solution at all? Take, for example, $b=(1,1)^T$.

Comment: You should specify b!

Comment: For $Ax=b$ to have *any* solution at all, $b$ must be an element of the column space of $A$.

Comment: More generally, if x_0 suffices the equation and L(A,c) is the set of $y \in K^n$ sufficing Ay=c then:  L(A,b)=x_0+L(A,0) (A Quotient Space of Ker(A)). Since dim(Ker(A))=1 => For every b for which such a x_0 exists, so that Ax=b, there are infinitely many other solutions

Comment: In this case it is much more simple, so this would not be a proper answer, but not all matrices are of 2x2 dimension

Answer (score 3):

This is the general answer. We denote $[A\,|\, b]$ the augmented matrix:

> An $n\times n$ linear system $Ax = b$ has
>
> - One solution if the matrix $A$ has maximal rank ($n$);
> - An infinity of solutions if $A$ has rank $<n$ AND $\DeclareMathOperator{\rk}{rank}\rk [A\,|\, b]=\rk A$;
> - No solution if $A$ has rank $<n$ AND $\rk [A\,|\,b] >\rk A$.

Comment: In exercises it might be a good idea to calculate det(A) and det([A|b]) respectively, since proving linear independence by definition can get tedious with e.g. 3x3 matrices

Comment: But the augmented matrix is not a square matrix. It has no determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it as an augmented matrix with a general vector $b=(b_1,b_2)$. So apply your row reduction steps to $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&|&b_1\\-2&-1&|&b_2\end{bmatrix}$$then you can find a relationship with $b_1,b_2$ such that the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I tried that and I got $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&|&b_1\\0&0&|&b_2+b_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So what happens if $b_1+b_2\neq 0$?

Comment: No solution if b_1+b_2 != 0?

Comment: No, the system is inconsistent if $b_1+b_2=0$. Do you see why?

Comment: Oh... yeah I can see it

Comment: So if $b_1+b_2\neq 0$ there are no solutions, but what happens when $b_1+b_2=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Say $b=0$...

Then $2x_1+x_2=0$, where $x$ is $\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$

Choose *any* $x_2$, and then $2x_1=-x_2\implies x_1=\frac{-x_2}2$.

So $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-x_2}2\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution for any $x_2$.

So infinitely many solutions.

More generally, if $b_1=-b_2$, where $b={\begin{bmatrix} b_1\\ b_2  \end{bmatrix}}$ then $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{-x_2+b_1}2\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$ is a solution for any $x_2$...  To see this row reduce the general augmented matrix...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe that if $x = \begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$ then $Ax = \underbrace{x_1\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ -2\end{bmatrix} +  x_2\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{linear combination}}= (2x_1+x_2)\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$.